# How to change the menu in DRBL boot sequence?

Tags: pxe-boot, drbl

I have a DRBL server installed.

When the PXE boot statrs, the DRBL menu has 3 options
1. DRBL Load
2. Local OS if exists
3. Memory test.

The first option fires after 5 seconds, however, I would like to change it, so the default option will be the: Local OS.
This is to prevent of users loading a DRBL OS by mistake.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received my answer from [DRBL Forum](https://sourceforge.net/projects/drbl/forums/)

```
In the file

/tftpboot/nbi_img/pxelinux.cfg/default

are the settings to do this. (Note: if line begins with # that means it's commented out)

drbl is the default

label drbl
 MENU DEFAULT

change it

label drbl
#  MENU DEFAULT

then uncomment

label local
  MENU DEFAULT
  MENU HIDE
```